# Is there a way to make ReSharper check for correct file headers

Tags: resharper, stylecop

**Update:** Using [StyleCop for ReSharper Plugin](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop.ReSharper) did the trick for code analysis inside VS. But unfortunately it seems that ReSharper plugins don't work in ReSharper command line inspections.

---

Is there a way to make ReSharper check for correct file headers just like classic StyleCop did. I'm aware that there is a way to define file headers to be inserted in new files, but we are using Resharper command line inspections to check a rather big legacy codebase. So it would be helpful if there was an automatic check for correct file headers.

I'm referring to StyleCop rules SA1633 up to SA1649.

[image: StyleCop file header rules]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exacly an answer to your question but you can use editorconfig to increase the error level during build.
Refer to [roslyn editorconfig](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/.editorconfig#L148)